# Differences between validator.w3.org and jigsaw.w3.org css validator?

Tags: css, validation, w3c

I tested both css validators to test my css3 document.
The jigsaw.w3.org validator pass my document with zero errors, but the validator.w3.org find a lot of errors.
Some of these errors are related with border-radius, rgba(), :not(), box-shadow and transform: skew...

Anyone know why these differences?

Any problem if i get errors on validator.w3.org and no errors on jigsaw.w3.org?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://validator.w3.org/ checks markup (HTML, XHTML, SVG etc.), not CSS.

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ checks CSS, not markup.